# When does .Net Use the Value Instead of a Pointer

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have noticed something throughout the years and never put much thought into it since I don't typically run across it. However, I am curious to see if someone can explain why certain objects will set themselves as a pointer to another instead of using the value of the object. This probably isn't exactly going on, but that's the best way I can try to explain it. I apologize if similar questions have been asked, I haven't been able to find them.

Take for instance the following example:

```
    If True Then
        Dim t1 As TextBox = New TextBox()
        t1.Text = "test"

        Dim t2 As TextBox = t1

        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test"

        t1.Text = "test2"
        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test2"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test2"

        t2.Text = "test3"
        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test3"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test3"
    End If

    If True Then
        Dim t1 As TextBox = New TextBox()
        t1.Text = "test"

        Dim t2 As TextBox = New TextBox()
        t2.Text = t1.Text

        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test"

        t1.Text = "test2"
        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test2"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test"

        t2.Text = "test3"
        Console.WriteLine(t1.Text) 'Outputs "test2"
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Text) 'Outputs "test3"
    End If
```

As you can, when I set the object equal to another, it does not create a new object but instead a pointer. Any modifications to either object will affect both of the objects. If I choose just one property, such as the Text property and set that equal to each other, they both act independently. Also, if I repeat the same logic and use strings or integers, and set one string equal to another string, both strings act independently and are not affected by modifications to the other.

So my question really is why isn't a new identical object created in memory when I set the two (textboxes in this example) equal to each other, but others do such as strings or integers? How does it decide that some objects will be pointers and others will use the values? Furthermore, is there an easy way to create a new copy of an object without manually having to set each property equal to the other's?

Comment: You don't set one *object* equal to another. You set one *variable* such that its new value is the same value as another *variable*'s value. It's really important to distinguish between variables and objects - and indeed between objects and references. Next, you should read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html (It's couched in C# terms, but hopefully you'll be able to understand the examples anyway.)

Comment: I tried to explain things in the simplest manner possible, so I used the term "object" to describe any "object" type that I am using to apply this logic to. Obviously as the example shows, I am setting one variable to another. What I was asking, which your article does not clear up, is why setting a string variable to another string variable results in a new string with the value assigned and not a reference to the other string, but setting a TextBox variable to another TextBox variable does result in a reference to the other.

Comment: The point is that terminology *matters* - an object isn't a variable, and it's worth being precise about this *particularly* when you're try to talk about the very specific issues around this. Both `TextBox` and `String` behave as reference types though - an assignment from one `string` variable (or property) to another will *only* ever copy the reference. The real difference between your examples is that in the first case, both `t1` and `t2` have values which refer to the same `TextBox`... so if you make a change to that object's data through *either* variable, it's equivalent.

Comment: You are again assuming that I understood the terminology involved such as reference vs value types, which was exactly the key phrase that I needed, which someone pointed out below. My question basically was asking "why do strings always copy the value but others don't", so saying that it will "only ever copy the reference" does not explain why it does so. I have found an article that explains what I am looking for in depth, in case anyone else has similar questions: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: I didn't assume that to start with: my comment was meant to be *correcting* your use of terminology, and giving you more information via the article. Then when you said "I tried to explain things in the simplest manner possible" I interpreted that to mean "Yes, I know the right terminology, I just wasn't being precise with it." I'm glad Joe's article has helped you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're talking about is simply the difference between value types (basically structures) and reference types (basically classes).  A value type variable contains an object while a reference type variable contains a reference to an object.  When you assign one variable to another you copy the contents of the variable.  For value type variables you are copying the value, i.e. the object, while for reference type variables you copy the reference to the object, so there's still just one object.

String is a class, i.e. a reference type, and it behaves exactly like all other reference types.  It may appear not to at times because any operation on a String actually creates a new String object rather then modifying the existing instance.  To prove that it behaves like other reference types, try this:

```
Dim s1 As String = "Hello World"
Dim s2 As String = s1

If s1 Is s2 Then
    Console.WriteLine("s1 and s2 refer to the same object.")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("s1 and s2 do not refer to the same object.")
End If
```